# YII2 How to get data in multi level relations with hasMany relations

Tags: php, yii2

I got 3 tables:

Network, Company, Departments

Network

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Network1 |
| 2 | Network2 |

Company

| id | network_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Company 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Company 2 |

Departments

| id | company_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Dep 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Dep 2 |
| 3 | 2 | Dep 3 |
| 4 | 2 | Dep 4 |

I have ActiveRecord relations

In Network Model

```
public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Company::className(), ['network_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

In Company Model

```
public function getDepartment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Department::className(), ['company_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

I need to get all Departments from Network id = 1 in Network Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like:

```
$results = Network::find()
    ->joinWith('company')
    ->joinWith('company.department')
    ->where(['network.id' => 1])
    ->all();
```

And your foreach:

```
if($results){
    foreach($results as $result){
        if($companies = $result->company){ 
            foreach($companies as $company){ //foreach you companies attached to network One
                if($departments = $company->department){
                    foreach($departments as $department){ //foreach you departments attached to every company
                        echo $department->name.' (Company: '.$company->name.')';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other way, that I think is better

```
$departments = Department::find()
    ->leftJoin('company', 'company.id = department.company_id')
    ->where('company.network_id = 1')
    ->all();
```

It depends what data you need to show.

PS. In your `Department` have to have relation to `Company` and can use it